# Issue with using timers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I wrote a timer to show to the user how much he/she is in this current scene:

```
timer_txt.x = 352;
timer_txt.y = 705;
var nCount: Number = 0;
var myTimer: Timer = new Timer(50, nCount);

timer_txt.text = "Time: " + nCount.toString();
myTimer.start();

function countUp(e: TimerEvent): void {
   nCount++;
   timer_txt.text = "Time: " + nCount.toString();
   if (nCount > 60) {
      var formattedTime =
        ((Math.floor(nCount / 60)) + ":" + (nCount % 60 >= 10 ? "" : "0") + (nCount % 60));
      timer_txt.text = "Time: " + formattedTime.toString();
   }
}
```

I have a `reset` button to reset the other objects on the scene but not the `timer`.

My problems are:

1. Whenever I click on the `reset` button, the `timer` is getting slower and slower and I do not know why while I am not making any changes in the timer. 
   I have many `flags` and many `child` on the stage. When the user click/touch on the `reset` button, all `flags` will be equal to `0` and all `child` will be `removed` and `add` again to the stage.
2. When the user is going to other scene (the timer should stop working while the current value of the timer needs to be saved in a variable) and when the user come back to this scene again this timer should work like: `previous value + counting the time`.
3. When ever I open it in my mobile phone, the speed of it is different from the PC. Is there any solution to code it to be compatible with the timing of the native device?
   this is a function that I wrote:

   ```
   function timerAtoB(firstColor: int): void {
      lineColor = firstColor;
      //GRID;
      //Path A to B
      var PathAB: Grid;
      PathAB = new Grid(4, 35, 20, 22, canvas, lineColor);
      this.addChild(PathAB);
   }
   ```

This function is to connect A dimension to B dimension. The connection between A and B will be constructed using a class called `Grid`- this class is to find the shortest path between the A and B and make the connection between them (that I don't want to go through it more than this as it is more complicated).

and I call this function with some delay:

```
delayCallFunctions(1000, timerAtoB, wireColor);
```

When I run it in my mobile, this delay will work properly but not in a correct time. For example, I wrote `1000ms` means execute the function after about `1 sec`, but in my mobile it takes more than `1 sec` to execute the function.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: For the second issue, I have used a class of variable. Every time that user go out of the scene, the current value will send to the class and when the user come back to the same scene the class will pass the variable to the scene. but obviously it is not working properly!

Comment: You don't have a listener on your timer

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is likely that everytime you revisit the frame that has this code you've posted, another timer instance is created.

```
var nCount: Number = 0;
var myTimer: Timer = new Timer(50, nCount);
```

That code will reset your nCount to 0, and create a new timer every single time you visit the frame.

Most likely, what you want to do is:

```
//just declare the vars
var nCount:Number;
var myTimer:Timer;

//assign them a value only if they are empty
if(nCount === NaN) nCount = 0;
if(!myTimer) myTimer = new Timer(50, 0);
```

You'll also want to do `myTimer.stop();` whenever you leave the scene.

The speed difference between your desktop/mobile is likely related to performance as 50ms delay is not a lot of time to do anything computationally complex and the mobile device may not be able to keep up and thus will be slower.   consider upping that delay to 100ms or even 250ms to see if it helps. Also, get rid of the `formattedTime` var as it's not needed and will the timer will perform better without it.

As a tip, you don't actually need an `nCount` var, as the timer itself has `currentCount` property that tracks how many times it's ticked since the last `timer.reset()`

Comment: Thanks for your hints and nice answer. The Second issue is solved but the First and Third issue is still remains even I assign '1000ms' for timer.

Comment: If you'd like help with item 1 in your question, please edit your question to include the relevant code (whatever code your reset button triggers).  For #3, maybe explain a bit more about what is happening and how you are determining there is a speed difference?

Comment: I Have edited the question and gave more information about my questions. Please let me know, if there is any further information needed.